# I'm getting header file doesn't exist error upon compiling (c++)

Tags: c++, compilation, imgui

I'm making a simple opengl app that renders a triangle and gui from ImGui. I am using windows 10 vscode.

I followed a beginner's tutorial from
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLPaoO-vpZnumdcb4tZc4x5Q-v7CkrQ6M-
and after getting program to render triangle, I followed Cherno's tut https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nVaQuNXueFw&t=253s to integrate imgui.

During compiling, I get:
[image]

I've tried to go to these files and change the header file path and it shows a new error:

[image]

what am I doing wrong? and how to fix it?

steps to reproduce:

1. Open editor at main folder(root) and use makefile command to compile the src.
2. Now the first type of error is displayed
3. After changing header path in imgui_opengl3.cpp and
   imgui_impl_glfw.pp to <imgui\imgui.h> <imgui\imgui_impl_opengl3.h>
   and <imgui\imgui_impl_opengl3_loader.h>
4. The second kind of error is obtained

5mb file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SATyP19EOs6_Bepoy-UgtyUpuOyBKsMf/view?usp=sharing

I'm new to c++ programming. I'd really appreciate your help!

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the error log in the question.

Comment: Presumably you are failing to link with the library that defines the undefined references.